# MUI's Chip Component change background color when selected

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, material-ui

I'm working in react and using MUI's `Chip` component. I would like to make it so that it will change the background color once it is selected instead of the generic default color.

[image]

I have tried using the 'global styles', if you will to change the background color when user clicks on the component.

Please see below for what I mean:

```
tokenChip: {
    height: '40px',
    width: '125px',
    fontSize: '18px',
    '&:hover': {
      backgroundColor: 'red'
    }

      <Chip
        className={ classes.tokenChip }
        clickable
classes={{ clickableColorPrimary: 'red', clickableColorSecondary:'blue'
        avatar={<Avatar
          style={{ padding: '2px' }}
          alt="Clickable"
          />}
        label="Clickable"
        variant="filled" />
```

I tried to see if the hover attribute in the CSS object did anything, but it didn't.

Comment: try the `:active` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

This is codesandbox example to change color for `Chip` and to add hover color. I have added 2 elements, one with `color` and one without `color` property.
https://codesandbox.io/s/chip-https-stackoverflow-com-questions-69652571-material-uis-chip-component-change-background-color-when-it-is-selected-cv8ud?file=/src/App.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import {Chip} from '@material-ui/core';


export default function App({classes}) {

  const handleClick = () => {
    alert('You clicked the Chip.');
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Chip
        className="tokenChip" 
        label="Clickable"
        onClick={handleClick}
      />  
      <Chip
        className="tokenChip2" 
        label="Clickable"
        color="primary"
        onClick={handleClick}
      /> 
    </div>
  );
}
.tokenChip {
  background-color: pink;
  width: 100px;
}
.MuiChip-clickable:hover {
    background-color: yellow;
}
.MuiChip-clickableColorPrimary:hover {
  background-color: black;
}
```

To read more on Chip - https://mui.com/components/chips/

Answer (score 1):

You can change the `Chip` following props based on the selected state to control its display (See this interactive [example](https://mui.com/components/chips/#chip-playground)):

- `color`: Change the color of the `Chip`.
- `variant`: Change the border color or background color of the `Chip` using the `color` prop above.
- `deleteIcon`: Display the suffix icon.
- `onDelete`: Pass an empty function to show the suffix icon, if it's empty, the icon is hidden.

```
const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState(false);

return (
  <Chip
    onClick={() => setSelected((s) => !s)}
    onDelete={selected && (() => {})}
    color={selected ? "primary" : "default"}
    variant={selected ? "default" : "outlined"}
    deleteIcon={<Done />}
    label="Choice"
    avatar={<Avatar alt="Natacha" src="/static/images/avatar/1.jpg" />}
  />
);
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: how would you modify this to accommodate an array of chips where the unique chip clicked only changes the `color`